# afterend is undefined in bookmarklet code

Tags: javascript, undefined

I am experimenting with afterend and I keep getting undefined as a result.

I am creating an experimental bookmarklet to alert when ARIA attribute aria-haspopup is not followed by the correct container role according to specification (A common error in development).

When I run the following JS I get 'Cannot read property 'insertAdjacentHTML' of undefined' in Chrome console.

Running the script in the console the results display on screen but 'undefined' is listed in the comsole.

```
 javascript:(function(){document.querySelectorAll('input[aria-haspopup="true"]')[0].insertAdjacentHTML('afterend', '<div id="hasTrue">The input aria-haspopup is true. A container with role menu or menubar must popup</div>');})();
    javascript:(function(){var a=document.createElement('style'),b;document.head.appendChild(a);b=a.sheet;b.insertRule('#hasTrue{border: 2px solid red;display:block;max-width: 15em;padding: 0.5em;text-align: center; line-height="1.5;}',0);})();
```

I'd appreciate any feedback and advise.

Comment: Is there an input element with the property `aria-haspopup` set to `true`?

Comment: Yes. I did test before asking.